# What is the difference between gridApi and gridOptions in AgGrid v28

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm asking this because I'm confused between the two. Is `gridApi` a part of 'gridOptions' or is it the reverse. I'm carefully going through the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-api/). I was assuming that "Grid API" is independent of "Grid Options". But then when i wanted to set column size why the document says do this:

[image]

so, when i do the ssame:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  ...
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>

_______________________________________________________

  gridOptions: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions.columnApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
```

I'm getting one error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.gridOptions is undefined

Clearly I've misunderstood something. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

- Grid Options are used to set grid properties before the grid is
  initialized.

you can have your gridOptions like this and call initGrid() inside ngOnInit():

```
initGrid() {

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{

      aggFuncs: {

        // this overrides the grids built-in sum function
        'mySum' : this.aggregate
      },
      suppressCopyRowsToClipboard: true,
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
      },
    };
```

- Grid Api is used after the grid is initialized.

So have a  "onGridReady($event);" in your html like this and call onGridReady(params) in your ts file.

```
 <ag-grid-angular>
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event);"   
 </ag-grid-angular>

onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridColumnApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gridOption is used to initialize grid beforehand, and gridAPI is used after the whole grid is initialized, both are used to interact with the grid but they have their own purpose.

gridOption is initialized as:-

. Initialize gridOption object
. Define grid columns and grid data
. Define the grid behaviour and features
. Pass the gridOption object.

gridAPI is initialized as :-

. AG Grid is initialized.
. This grid is accessed through event callback called as gridReady.
. It provides a reference for grid to perform programmatically.